# Direct Wiring (bypass thermostat) of heatpump cooling

Tags: wiring, thermostat, cooling, heat-pump

Last September my CT80 radiothermostat would not signal cooling despite the measured temperature exceeding the temperature setpoint.  It would be nice if a relative could manually switch the cooling on.

Is it possible or to wire in a manual switch to force (jump) the  Red node to the Green (Fan) and Yellow (cooling) nodes?

- RED NODE ===wire===switch===wire===Green node
- RED NODE ===wire===switch===wire===Yellow node

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Answer (score 0):

A manual switch to engage cooling is a bad idea because it could be inadvertently left on.
A better solution would be to have a second, basic thermostat. Wire them both in using a DPDT switch. One side would be the radiothermostat side, the other one is your relative stat.

Radio stat - - - equipment - - - relative stat
Y____________Y_______/-_______Y
G____________G______/-_______G

This way you can't get conflicts between the stats and no manual cooling issues.

**Here's an better illustration**
[image]
You don't need to use a rocker switch like in the picture any number of styles are available.

The key point is that the system is always working off 1 stat. If you wanted to set up the heat the same way you would wire it in a similar fashion but with a triple pole single throw (TPST) switch. They are a little harder to come by but still available in many styles.

Comment: I can elaborate on that later if it's not clear, I don't have a pen or paper right now.